# Understanding the concepts of embedding in Roberta architecture?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language-processing, python

I'm reading the [implementation file of Roberta architecture](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py), specifically in the [RobertaEmbedding class](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/3f69f415adcbdaedec154ba8eac220ef3276975d/src/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py#L65), this class has the comment:

```
Same as BertEmbeddings with a tiny tweak for positional embeddings indexing.
```

I'm a newbie to this, I want to ask about the changes in the `RobertaEmbedding class`, are these changes related to the dynamic masking in Roberta architecture? Thanks

Comment: I am not much familiar with roberta or bert, But Embedding is generally used to transform categorical ids to meaningful vectors (so that they can be processed by NN) which are generally learned by back-propagation (for instance use code tf.keras.layers.embedding) because transformers (well, those few i know) do not use rnn, they need a technique to know the order of the words. They do this by using positional embedding which can be done in the same way or y using for instance sin and cos bases. dynamic masking I think is related to masking words ahead so that decoder cannt see ahead.

Comment: Can you please formulate the title as a specific question? Thanks.